# How to validate a musical note with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate user input that should be a valid note. In music, notes are letters A-G and can be either sharp(#) or flat(b). Notes don't have to be sharp or flat, they can be natural. Why is this regex not matching the # or b in any of the notes?  Here is a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/oO8bU5/1).

```
([A-G]{1})(\#|b{1})?
```

Here is a list of all inputs that should match:

```
A
A#
Ab
B
Bb
C
C#
Cb
D
D#
Db
E
Eb
F
F#
Fb
G
G#
Gb
```

P.S.  E# and B# don't exist in music, so I'll have to program that into my code.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex:

```
([A-G]{1})(\#|b{1})?
```

Is correct.

To make your demo work, you need to remove the `x` modifier, as it affects `#` chars (it is a confusing modifier, actually). When you remove it, it shows your regex works ([updated demo here](https://regex101.com/r/vG0hB3/1)).

About the `x` modifier:

> `x` modifier: **Ignore whitespace**
>
> This flag tells the engine to ignore all whitespace and allow for comments in the regex. Comments are indicated by a starting "`#`"-character.

Now, if I may, you can simplify it by removing those `{1}`, they are redundant (they default is match once already). Also, as noted by [CSᵠ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/731947/cs%E1%B5%A0) (see [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100192/how-to-validate-a-musical-note-with-regex/34100212?noredirect=1#comment55965078_34100212)), that `#` doesn't need escaping and then `\#|b` could become `[#b]`:

```
([A-G])([#b])?
```

Of course, if you don't need to match the note (the first group) or the sharp/flat symbols (the second group) individually, you can remove parentheses as well.

Other than that, you can add the `gm` modifiers to test multiple lines: [DEMO here](https://regex101.com/r/fC1uB5/2).

---

### Bonus:

You don't have to program, you can *not* match `E#` and `B#` using regex only:

```
(?![EB]#)([A-G])([#b])?
```

[This demo](https://regex101.com/r/nL4cX9/2) shows it working. The `(?! ... )` is known as [*negative lookahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead).

Comment: maybe also note that `#` doesn't need escaping and then `\#|b` could become `[#b]`

Comment: @CSᵠ yes, that's right! I completely overlooked that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must need to include anchors and also you have to enable multiline modifier `m`.

```
^([A-G]{1})(\#|b{1})?$
```

or

```
^[A-G][#b]?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oO8bU5/3)

Comment: I am currently testing this in regex101.  I included a link to it.  They include the anchors for you.

Comment: enable `m` modifier. And no, they won't include anchors check https://regex101.com/r/oO8bU5/4